# JSF convertDateTime with timezone in datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, timezone

Trying to output a list of items in a datatable, like this:

```
<t:dataTable value="#{mybean.list}" var="item">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.time}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"  timeZone="#{item.timeZone}" />
            </h:outputText>
        </h:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

It always formats the time in GMT. It works as expected if I use a string constant or a bean which isn't the datatable variable (like '#{mybean.timeZone}').

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately, that's the nature of `<f:xxx>` tags. When the view is to be built, a single instance of the tag is been built where the converter is instantiated. All of its attribtues are been read and set only once. At the moment the view is been built, the `#{item}` resolves to `null` (it's only available during rendering of the view), so the `timeZone` attribute will be `null` and then default to UTC. When the view is to be rendered, the very same converter instance is been reused for each row of the table.

There are several ways to solve this. I can think of a custom converter or an EL function. I think a custom converter is after all the best as it can then also be reused in input components. The following kickoff example should work out for you (nullchecks and on omitted for brevity):

```java
@FacesConverter("extendedDateTimeConverter")
public class ExtendedDateTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        setPattern((String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern"));
        setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone((String) component.getAttributes().get("timeZone")));
        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        setPattern((String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern"));
        setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone((String) component.getAttributes().get("timeZone")));
        return super.getAsString(context, component, value);
    }

}
```

which can be used as

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{item.time}">
    <f:converter converterId="extendedDateTimeConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern" value="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ" />
    <f:attribute name="timeZone" value="#{item.timeZone}" />
</h:outputText>
```

This way the timezone is resolved everytime the converter is invoked instead of during its construction.

---

**Update**: the [OmniFaces `<o:converter>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/converter) solves exactly this problem without the need for a custom converter.

```
<h:outputText value="#{item.time}">
    <o:converter converterId="javax.faces.DateTime" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ" timeZone="#{item.timeZone}" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: The converterId must still be fixed in omnifaces converter. Is it possible to set converterId dynamically

Comment: Having to add a class or use a third party solution is unacceptable. I've given Faces so many chances, and it just continues to disappoint.