# Does a converter always run before Model View is updated?

Tags: jsf-2

Example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.timezone}>
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableTimezones} ... >
        <f:ajax render="currenttime" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>

<h:form id="currenttime">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.currentTime}" >
        <f:convertDateTime dateStyle="short" type="both" timeZone="#{bean.timezone}" />
    </h:outputText>
</h:form>

<!-- bean.currentTime is of type 'Date' -->
```

In the example, changing the timezone should cause the text in `currenttime` to show in the proper timezone. But it doesn't.

I figured this happens because converters are calculated in "Apply Request" phase and the value of the selected timezone is updated in "Update Model" phase.

Am I right?
Should I not use converters for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your h:selectOneMenu also in a form?

Comment: Yes, a different form than the one the output text is in. Tnx for the comment, i'll update the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your concrete problem is caused because `<f:convertDateTime>` is initialized during view build time, not during view render time ([exactly like JSTL and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)). Indeed, this runs far before update model values phase and hence the converter will not get set with the user-submitted timezone during view render time.

This problem has basically the same grounds as answered in the following answers:

- [How to set converter properties for each row of a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable/7531284#7531284)
- [JSF convertDateTime with timezone in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122460/jsf-convertdatetime-with-timezone-in-datatable/7123153#7123153)

One of the ways is managing and binding the converter instance as a bean property.

```
private DateTimeConverter converter;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    converter = new DateTimeConverter();
    converter.setDateStyle("short");
    converter.setType("both");
}

public DateTimeConverter getDateTimeConverter() {
    converter.setTimeZone(timezone);
    return converter;
}
```

With

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.currentTime}" >
    <f:converter binding="#{bean.dateTimeConverter}" />
</h:outputText>
```

An alternative is using [OmniFaces `<o:converter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/converter) which supports rendertime evaluation of converter's properties:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.currentTime}" >
    <o:converter converterId="javax.faces.DateTime" dateStyle="short" type="both" timeZone="#{bean.timezone}" />
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: omnifaces <3 

Nothing I like more then when it's available from it. It's becoming an obvious choice

Comment: I'm using Omnifaces and loving it so the choice here is clear :-)