# Update timeZone f:convertDateTime

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, timezone, converters

When I change **timeZone** of [f:convertDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/convertDateTime.html) this doesn´t change.

```
`<p:dataTable id="tabla2" value="#{bb.dataTable}" var="trm" resizableColumns="true"
    style="width : 1400px" editable="true" editMode="cell"
    rowStyleClass="#{styleController.daColoresParaEstadoTramos(trm, bb.fechaInicio)}"><p:column>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{trm.tramo.horaDespeguePrevista}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm" timeZone="#{bb.zonaH}" />
                </h:outputText>
            </f:facet>  
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputMask value="#{trm.tramo.horaDespeguePrevista}" mask="99:99" >
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm" timeZone="#{bb.zona}" />
                </p:inputMask>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>         
    </p:column></p:dataTable>`
```

zone is a element [java.util.TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html). I use primefaces 3.5

Comment: try adding <context-param><param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name><param-value>true</param-value></context-param>

Comment: I had that param in web.xml.

Comment: @PriteshShah: sorry, but this is complete nonsense. The OP is attempting to explicitly set `timeZone` attribute which would always override the default.

Comment: Matthew, I have the impression that you have left out one rather crucial part from the question. The code posted so far works namely perfectly fine when placed in a completely blank `<h:body>` (which is what everyone expects from you when seeing JSF code snippets). However, you've in your real code most likely *actually* placed it inside an `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>` with a `var="bb"`. That detail should absolutely not be omitted from the question in such way that the problem can't be reproduced anymore by copypasting the code into a blank `<h:body>`.

Comment: BalusC, It´s inside ** p:datatable ** adn bb are backingBean. Thaks for help me you are The Master Chief of JSF.

Comment: Exactly as I guessed. Now, your problem is already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530560/how-to-set-converter-properties-for-each-row-of-a-datatable/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122460/jsf-convertdatetime-with-timezone-in-datatable/

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved a similar problem on my app. The issue is with the JSF lifecycle. Like you I was taking a collection of objects and using `f:convertDateTime` for a Date on each, using a timezone value (I'm showing bookings for various locations around the world).

Setting a breakpoint in the getter for my list of bookings and another in the `ConvertDateTimeHandler` I could see that JSF was tring to convert the date before I had even got the bookings from the backing bean.

I was using a `ui:repeat` and was able to resolve the issue by switching to using `c:forEach` from JSTL.

You may be able to do something similar if you don't have to have the Primefaces datatable. Otherwise you may be better off having a transient getter which returns a String of the date already formatted for the timezone in question.

A quick way to prove this would be to get the first object in your collection and put it through an `h:outputText` along with the `f:convertDateTime`. If it converts correctly then try an alternative to datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<f:ajax/>` to change the time.
Add following code on your xhtml.

```
        <p>
            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bb.zone}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{bb.timeZones}"/>
                <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{bb.changeZone()}" render="hour"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
        </p>
        <p>
            <h:outputText id="hour" value="#{bb.hour}">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm" timeZone="#{bb.zone}" />
            </h:outputText>
        </p>
```

And, add following code in your managed bean

```
    private Date hour=new Date();
    private String zone;
    private List<String> timeZones=new ArrayList<String>();
    public Bean() {
        timeZones= Arrays.asList( TimeZone.getAvailableIDs());
    }

    public void changeZone(){
    System.out.println("Time Zone : "+ zone);
    }
```

Comment: I copy your code but doesn´t change **hour** I don´t know why can´t change timeZone