# use a conditional format with convertNumber day/days

Tags: java, html, jsf

Is there any way to make a conditional formatting with `convertNumber` ?
i have a Table - one colomn displays a timespan in days. the problem:
it shows like

- 5 days
- 3 days
- 2 days
- 1 days

but i want it to show "1 day"

I am using this code

```
<h:column>
   <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Timespan" /></f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.days}">
       <f:convertNumber pattern="0.## days" />
   </h:outputText>
</h:column>
```

on an other part of the Application I use POI to export to an Excel Sheet.
there i set a cell format that accomplishes that need

```
CellStyle dayStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
dayStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("[=1]General \"day\";General \"days\""));
```

is there any way to do the same with jsf?
i don't want to make it something like this:

```
<h:column>
   <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="Timespan" /></f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.days}" rendered="#{bean.days != 1}">
       <f:convertNumber pattern="0.## days" />
   </h:outputText>
   <h:outputText value="#{bean.days}" rendered="bean.days == 1" value="1 day" />
</h:column>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For a task this specific, you can always implement your own subclass.

Comment: Custom converter, or even define a JSP function (was looking for the link to a previous answer, but I am not finding it).

Comment: Use a custom converter.

Comment: This problem has exactly the same grounds as asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122460/jsf-convertdatetime-with-timezone-in-datatable/

Comment: I used a custom Converter, like mensioned in the answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122460/jsf-convertdatetime-with-timezone-in-datatable/