# Using ValueExpression for f:convertNumber pattern attribute

Tags: jsf

According to [the TLD](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/convertNumber.html), convertNumber accepts ValueExpressions for its pattern attribute. But it doesn't seem to work (JSF 1.2 RI):

```
<h:outputText value="#{Test.numberValue}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#{Test.numberPattern}" />
</h:outputText>
```

outputs

```
0.0210000000000000013045120539345589349977
```

(Test.numberValue evaluates to `0.021`, Test.numberPattern to `"0.00%"`)
If I use a String literal, everything works fine:

```
<h:outputText value="#{Test.numberValue}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00%" />
</h:outputText>
```

outputs

```
2,10%
```

The `h:outputText` is part of a `h:dataTable` column, if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

> The `h:outputText` is part of a `h:dataTable` column, if that matters.

Found out that it *actually* matters, please see [this question about convertDateTime in a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122460/jsf-convertdatetime-with-timezone-in-datatable/). According to that (thanks to BalusC, as always), this is my solution:

Custom converter:

```
public class DynamicNumberConverter extends NumberConverter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        setPattern((String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern"));
        return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        setPattern((String) component.getAttributes().get("pattern"));
        return super.getAsString(context, component, value);
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<h:outputText value="#{Test.numberValue}">
    <f:converter converterId="DynamicNumberConverter" />
    <f:attribute name="pattern" value="#{Test.numberPattern}"/>
</h:outputText>
```